# Python strange send email behavior

Tags: python

I have basic script that can send properly emails:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import smtplib
  
sender = 'demo@mail.com'  
receivers = ['demo2@mail.com']  
message = """From:Email cronjob <demo@mail.com> Subject:  
Anything  
 
Some more text """    
message = message + "\nso far so good"
 
try:    
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')   
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers,message)             
   print "Successfully sent email" 
except SMTPException:    
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

With snippet above the email is properly sent, however if I put the same script as a method that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
 
def sendMail(text):    
    sender = 'demo@mail.com'    
    receivers = ['demo2@mail.com']
 
    message = """From: Email cronjob <demo@mail.com>    
    Subject: Anything
    Initial text    """       
    message = message + text
 
    try: 
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')  
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)  
       print "Successfully sent email"    
    except SMTPException:   
       print "Error: unable to send email"
    
sendMail("\nlet's try it")
```

The email is sent but the sender address, the email title and the recipient address are not longer visible in the received email, just the body text.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Indent your code properly and make sure the the email headers like From and Subject are in their own line separated by atleast a newline (\n) character and then there is the body of the email. You should have a consistent behavior in both your examples.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out:

message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: My subject\a title\n\n%s""" % (sender, receivers, results).

Thanks.

Comment: If Senthil Kumaran's answer helped you fix your issue, you should accept his answer. Also, this kind of response is best as a comment to the answer, not as it's own answer.